# Git push trying to push to different branch even though tracked

Tags: git, branch, repository

I've got a git repo setup with 4 branches:

- master
- dev
- johndev
- angular-routing

I'm currently working on `angular-routing` and tried pushing to `origin/angular-routing` with simply `git push` which worked, but I noticed that I got the following error:

`! [rejected]        johndev -> johndev (non-fast-forward)`

I get what the error means, that's fine, but I don't get why it's trying to push there in the first place. I have all my branches tracked to the same remote branches which seems to be setup properly. Running `git remote show origin` gives me the following :

```
Remote branches:
  angular-routing tracked
  dev             tracked
  johndev         tracked
  master          tracked
Local branches configured for 'git pull':
  angular-routing merges with remote angular-routing
  dev             merges with remote dev
  johndev         merges with remote johndev
  master          merges with remote master
Local refs configured for 'git push':
  angular-routing pushes to angular-routing (up to date)
  dev             pushes to dev             (up to date)
  johndev         pushes to johndev         (local out of date)
  master          pushes to master          (up to date)
```

As far as I can tell from this, it's setup properly so there is no reason for my `git push` on `angular-routing` to be attempting to push to `johndev` but it is.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is happening because of the setting of `push.default` is `matching`, which is the default.  This means that when you do a push without specifying what to push git will attempt to push all branches which already exist on the destination.

It sounds like you'd want to change that setting to `upstream`, which would cause it by default to only push the current branch to the remote branch which is configured as its upstream branch. This can be done with:

```
git config --global push.default upstream
```

Comment: Just a note, the factory default for a no-arg push will be changing in git 2.0  -- "matching' is a good setting for push.default, I like it, but it's not an easily-anticipated one.

Comment: You can also use `git push origin HEAD` which is both explicit yet less annoying to type than `git push origin some-long-branch-name:some-long-branch-name`

Comment: Ah that's perfect thanks! That was really bugging me. It's just so much nicer to just enter `git push`. Thanks guys :)